# merging two dataframe based on one column

Tags: python, pandas

How would I go about merging two dataframes

df1:

```
Name     height    weight
Michael  180        55
Larry    183        53
Shaq     210        100
```

df2:

```
   Relinquished DTD DNP outindefinitely outseason
   Larry         1   0      0             0
   Shaq          2   0      0             1
```

I want to merge the all the columns from df2 except column Relinquished and the values to be applied if the value of column Name matches that of column Relinquished. Relinquished column has names of players but only that has an injury record. I want to fill the rest of the players that is not in Relinquished column to be 0.

Expected output:

```
Name     height    weight  DTD DNP outindefinitely outseason
Michael  180        55      0   0      0              0 
Larry    183        53      1   0      0              0 
Shaq     210        100     2   0      0              1
```

Comment: How did David get a height and weight in the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the confunsion, ignore David

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? You could at the very least provide the data in a more convenient format...

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Michael", "Larry", "Shaq"], "height":[180, 183, 210], "weight":[55,52,100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Relinquished": ["Larry", "David"], "DTD":[1, 2], "DNP":[0, 0], "outindefinitely":[0, 0], "outseason":[0, 1]})
df2.head()
```

out:

```
      Relinquished  DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  outseason
0        Larry    1    0                0          0
1        David    2    0                0          1
```

We then have to rename column `Relinquished`  :

```
df2.rename({"Relinquished":"Name"}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

Out:

```
    Name  DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  outseason
0  Larry    1    0                0          0
1  David    2    0                0          1
```

Finally,

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on="Name").fillna(0)
print(merged)
```

Out:

```
      Name  height  weight  DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  outseason
0  Michael   180.0    55.0  0.0  0.0              0.0        0.0
1    Larry   183.0    52.0  1.0  0.0              0.0        0.0
2     Shaq   210.0   100.0  0.0  0.0              0.0        0.0
3    David     0.0     0.0  2.0  0.0              0.0        1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have renamed the Relinquished column but merging doesn't seem to work

Comment: I tried stats_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)  but it returns NAN values for all the injury count columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Michael', 'Larry', 'Shaq'], 'height': ['180', '183', '210'], 'weight': ['55', '53', '100'] }
data2 = {'Relinquished': ['Larry', 'Shaq'], 'DTD': ['1', '2'], 'DNP': ['0', '0'], 'outindefinitely': ['0', '0'], 'outseason': ['0', '1'] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)

final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='Name', right_on='Relinquished' )

final_df = final_df.fillna('0')

final_df
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing that with this. You can even make it simpler in a one liner if you want.

```
df2.rename(columns={"Relinquished": "Name"}, inplace=True)

df2 = df2.append(df1).fillna(0).groupby("Name").aggregate("sum")
```

Tested it in my env and it seems to work

```
         DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  outseason  height  weight
Name
David    2.0  0.0              0.0        1.0     0.0     0.0
Larry    1.0  0.0              0.0        0.0   180.0    55.0
Michael  0.0  0.0              0.0        0.0   180.0    55.0
Shaq     0.0  0.0              0.0        0.0   180.0    55.0
```

Comment: I renamed the column relinquished to name but I couldn't get the second line of code to work. Keeps showing error. Maybe I made a df1 using groupby?

Comment: In the first line I renamed column "Relinquished" to "Name" and it was in place.
The second line does the rest of it.